# Update Job Titles in AD via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

I have the following script to update the Users "Job Title" under the "Organization" of their Profile in AD

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
#properties from the csv
$user  = $_.user
$title = $_.title
Get-ADUser -$user | Set-ADUser -Title "$title"
}
```

I am running this directly on the box to no avail

The CSV file im using test is set like this: user,title,test.user,Test Script,
[CSV File Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbknH.png)

However, this is not updating the required field (I have over 400 users to update)

If i run the following:  set-aduser "test.user" -Title "Example"

The required field successfully updates!

What am I doing wrong in my original script, I thought it should loop through each entry of the CSV and do the above :(

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: `Get-ADUser -$user` -> `Get-ADUser $user`

Comment: Please don’t tell me that’s the only mistake :(!!!

Comment: Just a heads-up, since it seems you are pretty new to this, allways use `-WhatIf` when you test your commands/scripts on Production-Enviroment. This is pretty helpfull to protect you from possible typos / wrong commands while you're still testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten your script a bit. As long as your csv contains the "user" and the "title" row, the users exist and you have the appropriate permissions, the script below should work:

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.user -Title $_.title
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the above didn't actually error or work, I changed to: 
Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity "$_.user" -Title "$_.title"
}  also to no avail :( getting very frustrated *Cries loudly*

Comment: If you use quotes ( " ) in this situation, you need to write the variable like that: -Identity "$($_.user)" -Title "$($_.title)" .

Comment: Makes sense, but I dont understand why the shorten script doesn't error OR implement the command at this point

Comment: I have ventured to:

Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
#properties from the csv
    $user  = $_.user
    $title = $_.title

Set-ADUser -identity $_.user -Description $._title -Title $_.title 
}


Still to no avail, I feel there is an issue with the Set-ADUser -Identity but can't see why

Comment: If the there would be no such user in AD, would would seen an error message saying so. I've just tested my example in my lab and can't see any issues with it. How does your CSV look like?

Comment: Copy and Paste direct from the file

user,title,test.user,Test Script4,

Comment: Could you please edit your post and put a screenshot of your csv into it?

Comment: I have done above, whats weird is that it doesnt error and the below works:
set-aduser "test.user" -Description "Example Overwrite 1" -Title "Example Overwrite 1"

Comment: Your CSV is malformed, that's the issue. Write test.user,Test Script4 on a new line and everything will work

Comment: How is it malformed? (For future ref?)

I have made the amendment so the file opens as:
test.user,Test Script4

Using the powershell:
Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.user -Title $_.title
}


The command runs without error but executes nothing :( :( :(

Comment: I will read that now but I have solved it

I didnt even think the headers needed to be on a separate line

The end code that works:

Import-CSV -Path C:\UsersTestv1.CSV | Foreach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_.user -Title $_.title 
}


Thank you for all your assistance and help; I am learning as best I can and hope to be as helpful as the majority of you guys :)

Comment: Ok so not actually working as expected

The CSV file displays the users as Test.User

How can I have the script pull this detail to match it to the beginning of the email address to match each user??

The script works if the user doesn't have an email address specified in AD (whihc my test users dont)

Comment: So I've moved to:

#Imports Usernames and Jobtitles from CSV File
Import-CSV -Path C:\'UserUpdatev2.CSV' | Foreach-Object {

$user = $_.user
$title = $_.title

#Selects the specified user and sets Job Title
Get-ADUser -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -eq "$_.user")} | Set-ADUser -Title $_.title 
}

Hoping this would select each user via the UPN (i have amended the CSV to add the @companyname.com for each user)

The script, again it runs but its not actually making any changes!!